# How to use the basic authentication in NestJS?

Tags: get, nestjs, basic-authentication, httpservice

So I'm trying to do an API call, and I have to use basic authentication.

The codes are like these :

```
const headersRequest = {
    'Content-Type'  : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : `Basic ${this.authToken}`
}

let response = this.httpService.get(url, {headers: headersRequest});
```

The question is the above `get()` function call correct?

Because the output of :

```
console.log(response)
```

is :

```
Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] }
```

and not the response object which I wanted.

I have tried to explore `HttpService get`, but couldn't find any detailed documentation related to this basic authentication.

PS: I'm a PHP developer and just learned NestJS in the last couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the proper result from the observable is to to just convert it to a promise in this case.

`const response = await this.httpService.get(url, {headers: headersRequest}).toPromise()`